# How to implement the excel function IF(H3>I3,C2,0) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In column J would like to get the value as per excel function ie IF(H3>I3,C2,0) and based on that occurance value ie from bottom to up 1st occurance as the latest one and next to that is 2nd occurance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NExXb.png)

Comment: IIUC, you can try using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# suppose we have this DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[55,23,11,100,9] , 'B':[12,72,35,4,100]})

# suppose we want to reflect values of 'A' column if its values are equal or more than values in 'B' column, otherwise return 0
# so i'll make another column named 'Result' to put the results in it
df['Result'] = np.where(df['A'] >= df['B'] , df['A'] , 0)
```

then if you try to print DataFrame:

```py
df
```

result:

```py
    A      B      Result
0   55     12     55
1   11     72     0
2   23     35     0
3   100    4      100
4   9      100    0
```